# C++ library main() name conflict

Tags: c++, linker, namespaces

I'm using the Tesseract OCR library in an iOS project. My project is built in RubyMotion, which is unable to link the Tesseract lib because of a duplicate symbol:

```
Link ./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.0-Development/myapp.app/myapp
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/Me/Documents/myapp/vendor/Tesseract/libtesseract_all.a(svpaint.o)
    ./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.0-Development/objs/main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
```

Grepping the project found 20 instances of int main(). Is there a way to rename the main() functions, or otherwise resolve this symbol conflict?

Comment: You could try declaring them static, which will make them visible only within the file they are defined in (which will have the side effect of preventing symbol conflicts between files).

Comment: You're sure you haven't accidentally linked in a bunch of Tesseract code samples, each with it's own 'main()' function??

Comment: Any luck with solving this?

Comment: @ChrisMitchelmore No, but I recently found https://github.com/Ferdev/motion-tesseract . If you try that library and find that it works, please let me know!

Comment: I managed to fix it, no idea why it works, but I had it set up in another test project before integrating and it was working. Eventually I just built a new project from scratch and copied everything across and now it works. Fun.